# How is the while-loop iterating?

Tags: c++, string, while-loop

```
char *removeSpaces(char *str)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
           str[j++] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

I have read in one of the posts that while(n) is equal to while(n!=0), but what is happening in this case, just want to know how while(str[i]) is proceeding?

Answer (score 3):

The while loop terminates when `str[i]` evaluates to the null char `\0`. This char has the value of `0`. When this happens, the loop will terminate. It's not a good design, because the loop could continue to iterate beyond the length of the string (which is unsafe because it would be reading memory that isn't part of the string, possibly causing a segmentation fault.)

Comment: why could the loop continue to iterate beyond the lenght of the string? C-strings are terminated by a `\0` by definition

Comment: If it were a string literal, you'd be right. However, there's no guarantee that the caller has supplied a valid C-string.

Comment: So, what would be the correct syntax... while(str[i] != '\0'); or while(str[i] !=0); ?

Comment: They are equivalent, more or less. I prefer `while(str[i] != '\0')` because it is the clearest.